# How to create more space for Ubuntu Partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I wanted to create more space for Ubuntu on my hard disk taking it away from my Windows partition, so I booted the LiveCD and resized the NTFS partition.

Then I wanted to resize my Ubuntu (ext4) partition to fill up the created unallocated space.

Unfortunately I cannot add more space to the partition.

[A picture says more then a 1000 words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJZ47.png)

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: You need to move something for it. You do not have free space beside your Ubuntu partition. You can't just "add space" to any partition you like.

Comment: It looks like you shrinked the NTFS partition from a wrong side.

Comment: Sorry but your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to add space to Ubuntu or to Windows?

Comment: Eduardo Cola to ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

1. Make a [Full System Back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)
2. Move `/dev/sda3` all the way to the end of the disk
3. Commit
4. Let it work all night while you sleep
5. next day, extend the `/dev/sda4` as it now has free space next to it.

#### Done!  ;-)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**